# WPF RichTextBox with clickable UNC path

Tags: wpf, powershell, richtextbox

I'd like to know how to insert a clickable UNC path into my `RichTextBox` - like this:

```
file://c:\Test
```

A hyperlink is working, but it didn't find the way with UNC.

Thank you,

K.

I had a project using Windows Form and moving now to WPF. I can't find the equivalent of `LinkClicked` events for UNC

Comment: Sorry forgot to metion that I'm using using PowerShell to create the WPF controls

Comment: I;m using PowerShell to create WPF controls
Sorry, forgot to metion it

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I'm using to update the `RichTextbox`

```
function AppendText{
    param ($sender, $e, $Text)
        $FlowDocument = $Sender.Document
        $Paragraph = [System.Windows.Documents.Paragraph]::new()
        $FlowDocument.Blocks.Add($Paragraph)
        $Paragraph.Inlines.Add($Text)
}
```

How can I insert a clickable object ?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77002699/edit) your question instead of writing an answer.